# ProductMajorPart is always 0 while ProductVerison is OK?

Tags: c#

I have a problem about get `ProductMajorPart` of an EXE. It is always 0 as well as the `ProductMinorPart`, but `ProductVersion` is displayed as expected.

I already set the `FileVersion`, `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyInformationalVersion` in AssemblyInfo.cs, but none of them works.

My IDE is Visual Studio 2015.

[image: Debug in VS2015]

Code is like this:

```
Process[] processesByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("helloworld");
Process process = processesByName[0];
FileVersionInfo fileVersionInfo = process.MainModule.FileVersionInfo;
if(fileVersionInfo.ProductMajorPart =2 )
```

Comment: "1.2.3.456.78900" is not a valid version number.  Use, say, "1.2.3.456".